# Get some tenant identifier when signing in external account (Microsoft account)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm building SaaS web based application that needs to be able accept users from multiple Azure AD-s and there external users (usually Microsoft accounts). I created example and tried to see what I can get from access token.

Sample consists from one client application (.js) that uses MSAL library to handle authentication and two APIs that have protected endpoints. I also created three separate Azure AD applications AlanClient, AlanAPI1, AlanAPI2. Both AlanAPI1 and AlanAPI2 have API exposed (Expose an API section in Azure Portal application) and have specified one consumer AlanClient. AlanClient has permission to both APIs. All applications are registered with `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` and `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`.

I have multiple cases that I want to cover and as far I tested when I sign in with outlook account that is defined as external User in Azure AD (both Azure AD where application is originally registered and Azure AD that is another "tenant") I don't get any info (in token) about the tenant this account is registered.

Let me explain. I was hoping for something like this

`"tid": "value of Azure AD tenant where this account is registered as external user"` - If this account is regitered as external user in multiple tenants that use this app I will expect array of tenants or something like this.

Instead I get

`"tid": "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad"` which is value of "Microsoft presonal account tenant" as far I know.

EDIT:

Thanks to juunas answer in my client application I changed MSAL config `authority` from `authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'` to `authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations'` and also updated manifest value `signInAudience` with `AzureADMultipleOrgs`. 
Now I have situation where I have Azure AD called "A" and in this azure AD have registered my applications. Tenant A has external user called alan.p365@outlook.com and this workd fine. I can login with this account and I get tid parametar indicated value of tenant A. When I try to do this with Tenant B that has lovro.p365@outlook.com as external user this failed with message

**AADSTS50020**: User account 'lovro.p365@...' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'A' and cannot access the application AlanClient in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure AD user account.

Just to clarify I successfully singed in with tenant administrator of tenant B and tenant B has this applications in Enterprise applications list.

GitHub example project: https://github.com/alan994/AzureADTest

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58840270/login-from-microsoft-account-not-working-for-multitenant-azure-ad-application) about this but conclusion is that this is not supported with nothing except common endpoint in (v2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to utilise the Microsoft accounts that exist in AAD tenants, you have to use the organizations endpoint instead of the common endpoint.

Your app also should not allow personal accounts. So the signInAudience should be the multipleorgs one.

By allowing personal accounts, you are allowing their direct use, with that tenant id that is common for all of them.

Comment: Hi, that has solved a part of problem. Now when I try to login with account alan.p365@... that is registered in Azure Ad as external user this works fine. But when I try to login with account that is external user in other tenant that dosn't works. Tenant has this application.

AADSTS50020: User account 'lovro.p365@...' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'ESSPERTA' and cannot access the application AlanClient in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure AD user account.

Comment: What login page are you using (i.e. what is your authority)? Are you using a tenant-specific endpoint or organizations or common?

Comment: I published the code sample on github. https://github.com/alan994/AzureADTest 
`var msalConfig = {
 auth: {
  clientId: '6c2bd7d0-e90e-481f-8170-0fc701ec64ce',
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations',
  redirectURI: 'http://localhost:5500'
 },
 cache: {
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  storeAuthStateIncookie: true
 }
};`

Comment: Okay, I'll try this out later and see if I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: did you have any luck? I tried various combinations and still can't get this to work.

Comment: It seems I may have misunderstood that the organizations endpoint would work similarly to the older v1 common endpoint. It seems it does not. I can sign in with a Microsoft account that exists in the tenant where the app was registered, but not with another one. But it feels odd. I'll try pinging some AAD people on Twitter and see if they can explain this one better.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer and find another way of dealing with this problem. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Alright, the MS people responded that the "organizations" and "common" endpoints essentially do not sign in guests (though there is still that one special scenario). To sign in a guest in a tenant, you need to use the endpoint that identifies the tenant.

Comment: You are talking about this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848433/5980883) or something else?

Comment: Yeah that question actually seems a bit similar to yours, I saw it this morning :)

Comment: But the MS replies on Twitter to me are here: https://twitter.com/JoonasWestlin/status/1194669834728067074

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202313/discussion-between-alan-jagar-and-juunas).