# Login from Microsoft account not working for Multitenant Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm building multitenant SaaS web based application. Application is registered in my tenant and each customer with their office 365 subscription will get Service principal object in Azure AD.

**I'm having problem with login from external account (Microsoft account) in customer tenant.**

I created [example](https://github.com/alan994/AzureADTest) and tried to see what I can get from access token.

Sample consists from one client application (.js) that uses MSAL library to handle authentication and two APIs that have protected endpoints. I also created three separate Azure AD applications AlanClient, AlanAPI1, AlanAPI2. Both AlanAPI1 and AlanAPI2 have API exposed (Expose an API section in Azure Portal application) and have specified one consumer AlanClient. AlanClient has permission to both APIs. All applications are registered with "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 and "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs".

As far as I understood this should be enough to login with

1. Office 365 account from host tenant
2. Microsoft account that is registered as external user in host tenant
3. Office 365 account from guest tenant
4. **Microsoft account that is registered as external user in guest tenant**

Clarification:
 - host tenant --> Azure AD instance in which application is registered. In error message bellow tenant A.
 - guest tenant --> Azure AD instance that is only using application

**I have a problem with case no. 4**

I get this error message:
**AADSTS50020**: User account 'lovro.p365@...' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'A' and cannot access the application AlanClient in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure AD user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenes of 2 and 4 should be the same.

I have tested both and everything is OK.

You could use [OAuth 2.0 auth code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to have a test with it.

Construct a request to `login.microsoftonline.com` with your app configurations.

This URL will look like:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant A]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[client id of the Azure AD app registered in host tenant]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[redirect uri of the Azure AD app]&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`.

After signing in with credentials of Microsoft Account in tenant A, you will get a "code" in the address bar. Use this code to request access token:

```
POST /[tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

client_id=[client id of the Azure AD app registered in host tenant]
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&code=[code got from the previous step]
&redirect_uri=[redirect uri of the Azure AD app]
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Then we could get the access token for Microsoft Account as a guest user in tenant A.

Comment: Yeah, as I found out yesterday as well, guest accounts can only sign in through the endpoint that specifies the tenant id or domain. V1 supported those through the common endpoint though.

Comment: Hi thanks for help. My conclusion is the same. There is no way to login with external Microsoft account of guest tenant to application that uses any endpoint except common (in v2.0)

Comment: Allen Wu - I think we misunderstood  each other. External user in guest tenant has nothing to do with host tenant. Host tenant don't know that this user exists. And also host tenant and guest tenant don't have anything in common (no trust or anything else)

Comment: I don' think I have misunderstood you. In my steps, the user is a guest user of tenant A. Tenant A and host tenant have no trust with each other. The Azure AD app is registered in host tenant. Please have a try with my steps.

Comment: Ok sorry, now I understood. Basically I need to know what customer is trying to login and then redirect him to correct endpoint (endpoint that has his TID in url). I will try your answer. Thanks for help. Also similar response is here: https://twitter.com/JoonasWestlin/status/1194669834728067074